# Django template for loop is empty

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-2.2

I am trying to build a detail view in django, but nothing is displayed in the template.

views.py

```
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'detail.html'
```

detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% for item in itemlist %}
{{item.pk}}
{{item.title}}

{% empty %}
There are no items in this list

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Why is nothing displayed in the template here?

Comment: A `DetailView` has no `itemlist` passed to the template, (and a `ListView` neither).

Answer (score 1):

You do not pass a item with the name `itemlist` to the template in a `DetailView`. In a `ListView` (which looks more appropriate), it will by default use a context variable named `object_list`. Since the variable is not present, the [**`{% for … %}…{% endfor %}`** template block [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) will be resolved to the empty string.

If you want to pass the queryset of `Article`s to the context through the `itemlist` name, you can set the [**`context_object_name`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.context_object_name):

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class MyDetailView(ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'itemlist'
```

Comment: I already tryed, but then I get this Error

`TypeError at /detail/5/
'Article' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/5/`

Comment: Maybe is this because my URL? `path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.MyDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),`

Comment: @Snowball: for a `DetailView` the item is of course not iterable, since *one* article, well is not a collection of iterables.

Comment: @Snowball: give you have a `DetailView`, why do you use a `{% for ... %}` loop in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

As Willem told you in the comment, you're in a details view so you don't need a for loop to iterate , you can just show the details in the template like: {{item.pk}}

Comment: But when I use `ListView`, then I have all results and not only this one `PK` what I want